# Unable to write text to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write a lambda function in node.js to write the data passed in by the calling program into an s3 bucket. In later stages I'll hook it up to API Gateway so I can call it from an external application.

I've written the lambda and it works with no errors but nothing is being written to s3 when I run the test from the console.

I tried with and without the file already existing and I tried the full arn for the bucket.

The lambda has the roles required to perform the task.

I've tried various options including the use of promises. I've checked other code and copied in what should work but nothing is output and no errors in the console. If I add more console messages, everything round it works but nothing appears in the success or error brackets.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: 'eu-west-1'});
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-write-logs-to',
        Key: 'example2.txt',
          Body: 'Uploaded text using the promise-based method!'
        };
    var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise();
    putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
      console.log('Success');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    return response;
};
```

In the console I get the all text expected from the console messages and some log output but with no errors but it.

Comment: A thing to think about: You have an `async` function, but you never `await` anything.

Comment: Good point. I took that off but no difference.

Comment: Taking that off was not my point. ;) You *need* to `await` something (and the only things you can await are promises). Compare https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/.

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried taking the code sample from that page and still nothing. I then added an extra console writes in the catch but that didn't show up.

Comment: Update your question with your current code.

Comment: I've cut it down to the bare minimum

Comment: Your program should output *something* (success or error) now. Are you keeping it running long enough that the S3 call has a chance to complete?

Comment: Thanks for your help. There were 2 issues with the code. As you suggested the code was finishing before the write had completed and failed so I didn't get the error message. By putting

    var x = await s3.putObject(params).promise();

It did wait. 
The issue was I was writing text to the method which it interpreted as a file name. By converting to byte data it worked. 

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code is

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: 'eu-west-1'});
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-write-logs-to',
        Key: 'example2.txt',
        Body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event), 'utf8')
        };
    var x = await s3.putObject(params).promise();

    return;
};
```

Comment: You should comment on why this works. I do not think this is helpful for others.